# How to generate static hibernate models from kotlin class entity?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, maven, jpamodelgen

I have a `spring boot + kotlin + hibernate + maven` app. How can i generate hibernate static models?

With my current set up i get an error during compilation:

> cannot find symbol 
> symbol:   class SomeEntity 
> location: class com.default.SomeEntity_

For this line `@StaticMetamodel(SomeEntity.class)` which is in the generated class: `SomeEntity_`

My current kotlin maven plugin set up is:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <pluginOptions>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Embeddable</option>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                                    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

EDIT

After adding `<phase>process-classes</phase>` to kapt models got generated, but now code which uses them does not compile since it tries to access classes that will be generated after compilation.

```
                    <execution>
                    <id>kapt</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>kapt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <annotationProcessorPath>
                                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                            </annotationProcessorPath>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```